Accessing all EditText in ViewGroup getChildCount & getChildAt() vs getTouchables() vs getFocusables()
I'm trying to access all EditText which have been creating programmatically according to an array. As you know Java has getComponents() method which returns array of the components and which allows you to use enhanced for loop like below:
for(Component c : parent.getComponents()){
    if(c instanceof TextField){
        ...
    }
}

Normally I was using getChildCount() and getChildAt(int index) together:
for(int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++){
    if(parent.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText){
        ...
    }
}

While I was reading documentation and I saw getTouchables() method. From documentation:

Find and return all touchable views that are descendants of this view, possibly including this view if it is touchable itself

So I tried enhanced for loop with that method:
for(View v : parent.getTouchables()){
    if(v instanceof EditText){
        ...
    }
}

Above loop also works so I decided to search on the internet about getTouchables() method for getting more information but couldn't able to find anything. I saw this question but from answers only this answer suggests alternative method (getFocusables(int direction)) than using getChildCount() and getChildAt(int index) methods together.
For better understanding if we think about only EditText which one (getTouchables() vs. getFocusables(int direction) vs. getChildCount() & getChildAt(int index) together) is more suitable?

Accessing all programmatically created EditText views within a parent, stick with getChildCount() and getChildAt(). This approach is clear, efficient, and guarantees you'll find all EditText views, regardless of their focusability.

Thanks for your comment. I was thinking to use getTouchables() method. Never tested getFocusables() just saw from one answer which I shared question's link. If you have knowledge or if you know any source about those methods except documentation can you please share?

IMHO getFocusables() method returns an array of all touchable views within the parent, including the parent itself if it's touchable. While it might work for finding EditText views in your case (since EditText is inherently touchable), it's not ideal. For your specific scenario. It might include non-EditText views and introduce unnecessary overhead compared to getChildCount and getChildAt.

Doesn't it just focus on touchable views with getTouchables() method? If so, for finding EditText wouldn't a method with limited views (only touchable ones) be less overhead than handling all views (isn't this because all views contain both touchable and non-touchable views)?

getTouchables() might include views other than EditText, like Button or ImageView. It might miss non-touchable EditText views in your layout, depending on their configuration. Take this analogy and Imagine searching for apples in a basket. getTouchables() would check everything in the basket (apples, oranges, bananas), while getChildCount and getChildAt would directly access the apples. Hope this makes sense now and cleared your doubt.

I got your point. But to be honest I still have doubts. getTouchables() method gets all components which are touchable and can miss some views according to their attributes but when you use getChildAt() method doesn't it also get same views including non-touchable views? Isn't that why we have to check if it's EditText or not with if condition and instanceof even with getChildAt() method? Also getChildAt() can contain widgets (like Barrier). Aren't you going to have more views in your basket with getChildAt() method?
